# can't complete process of GPUImageMovieWriter completionBlock

Tags: ios, objective-c, gpuimage

When the completion Block is about to complete the process to set video brightness using GPUImage class, the output video is of 0 kb, and crashes on GPUImageMovieWriter.m file, and gives below error.

Proj_name(1232,0xb0219000) malloc: *** mach_vm_map(size=8388608) failed (error code=3)
*** error: can't allocate region securely
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

Is anybody here who had worked using GPUImage for video brightness??

Comment: I used dispatch_async method, not completionBlock because it is not getting compiled..

Answer (score 1):

GPUImageBrightnessFilter: Adjusts the brightness of the image

brightness: The adjusted brightness (-1.0 - 1.0, with 0.0 as the default)

https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage

check this above link..

Comment: but should i import whole github project, or just have to drag GPUImage files to my project.??